# What happened to thread.start_new_thread in python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I liked the ability to turn a function into a thread without the unnecessary line to define a class. I know about _thread, however it appears that you are not supposed to use _thread. Is there a good-practice equivalent of thread.start_new_thread for python 3?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
threading.Thread(target=some_callable_function).start()
```

or if you wish to pass arguments,

```
threading.Thread(target=some_callable_function,
        args=(tuple, of, args),
        kwargs={'dict': 'of', 'keyword': 'args'},
    ).start()
```

Comment: I am using method 2 to pass one argument to a thread, and am getting the error: argument after * must be sequence, not it. Do you know what this means?

Comment: Make sure you're passing `(firstarg,)` not `(firstarg)` - remember that single-element tuples need the trailing comma to be interpreted as a tuple.

Comment: What would the callable method signature look like? If I use something like `callable(**kwargs):` I get `TypeError: callable() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`, and if I use `callable(kwargs):` I get `TypeError: callable() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'`.

Comment: @henrikstroem `threading.Thread(target=callable,kwargs=kwargs)`

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is not a direct equivalent, because Python 3 is meant to be more portable than Python 2 and the `_thread` interface is seen as too low-level for this purpose.

In Python 3 the best practice is usually to use [`threading.Thread(target=f...)`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread). This uses different semantics, but is preferred because the interface is easier to port to other Python implementations.