# Multithreading in python3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, flask

im using multithreading in python3 with Flask as below.
Would like to know if there is any issue in below code, and if this is efficient way of using threads

```
import _thread
COUNT = 0

class Myfunction(Resource):

    @staticmethod
    def post():
        global GLOBAL_COUNT
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        request_json = request.get_json()

        logger.info(request_json)

        _thread.start_new_thread(Myfunction._handle_req, (COUNT, request_json))
        COUNT += 1

        return Response("Request Accepted", status=202, mimetype='application/json')

    @staticmethod
    def _handle_req(thread_id, request_json):
        with lock:


            empID = request_json.get("empId", "")

            myfunction2(thread_id,empID)

api.add_resource(Myfunction, '/Myfunction')
```

Answer (score 8):

I think the newer module threading would be better suited for python 3. Its more powerful.

```
import threading

threading.Thread(target=some_callable_function).start()
```

or if you wish to pass arguments

```
threading.Thread(target=some_callable_function,
    args=(tuple, of, args),
    kwargs={'dict': 'of', 'keyword': 'args'},
).start()
```

Unless you specifically need _thread for backwards compatibility. Not specifically related to how efficient your code is but good to know anyways.

see [What happened to thread.start_new_thread in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319268/what-happened-to-thread-start-new-thread-in-python-3) and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: can you provide more details when you say threading module is more powerful

Comment: _thread is for low level threading. There's additional methods in the threading module and also contains the Thread class that implements threading. If you go to that tutorial I supplied it goes into details on the differences between _thread and threading