# AttributeError: module 'thread' has no attribute 'start_new_thread'

Tags: python, debugpy

I am trying to get data from an endpoint on a website using Python, here is my code:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession as session

async def get_api_data(api_url):
    try:
        async with session.post(api_url, data={"limit": 10000, "page": 1}) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            data = asyncio.run(response.json())
            return data
    except session as e:
        print(f"Error getting API data: {e}")
        return None

asyncio.create_task(get_api_data("url"))
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 268, in run_file
    start_debugging(target)
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 258, in start_debugging
    debugpy.connect(options.address, access_token=options.adapter_access_token)
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\public_api.py", line 31, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py", line 143, in debug
    log.reraise_exception("{0}() failed:", func.__name__, level="info")
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py", line 141, in debug
    return func(address, settrace_kwargs, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py", line 297, in connect
    _settrace(host=host, port=port, client_access_token=access_token, **settrace_kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py", line 45, in _settrace
    return pydevd.settrace(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 2821, in settrace
    _locked_settrace(
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 2942, in _locked_settrace
    py_db.patch_threads()
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 2392, in patch_threads
    patch_thread_modules()
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 1205, in patch_thread_modules
    patch_thread_module(t)
  File "c:\Users\abdul\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 1168, in patch_thread_module
    _original_start_new_thread = thread_module._original_start_new_thread = thread_module.start_new_thread 
                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'thread' has no attribute 'start_new_thread'
```

When I checked the debugpy.py file, here are the lines I found:
I put a comment before the line causing the error, it is in the 8th line.

```
def patch_thread_module(thread_module):

    if getattr(thread_module, '_original_start_new_thread', None) is None:
        if thread_module is threading:
            if not hasattr(thread_module, '_start_new_thread'):
                return  # Jython doesn't have it.
            _original_start_new_thread = thread_module._original_start_new_thread = thread_module._start_new_thread
        else:
            #-----------This is the line causing the error--------
            _original_start_new_thread = thread_module._original_start_new_thread = thread_module.start_new_thread
    else:
        _original_start_new_thread = thread_module._original_start_new_thread

    class ClassWithPydevStartNewThread:

        def pydev_start_new_thread(self, function, args=(), kwargs={}):
            '''
            We need to replace the original thread_module.start_new_thread with this function so that threads started
            through it and not through the threading module are properly traced.
            '''
            return _original_start_new_thread(_UseNewThreadStartup(function, args, kwargs), ())

    # This is a hack for the situation where the thread_module.start_new_thread is declared inside a class, such as the one below
    # class F(object):
    #    start_new_thread = thread_module.start_new_thread
    #
    #    def start_it(self):
    #        self.start_new_thread(self.function, args, kwargs)
    # So, if it's an already bound method, calling self.start_new_thread won't really receive a different 'self' -- it
    # does work in the default case because in builtins self isn't passed either.
    pydev_start_new_thread = ClassWithPydevStartNewThread().pydev_start_new_thread

    try:
        # We need to replace the original thread_module.start_new_thread with this function so that threads started through
        # it and not through the threading module are properly traced.
        if thread_module is threading:
            thread_module._start_new_thread = pydev_start_new_thread
        else:
            thread_module.start_new_thread = pydev_start_new_thread
            thread_module.start_new = pydev_start_new_thread
    except:
        pass


def patch_thread_modules():
    for t in threading_modules_to_patch:
        patch_thread_module(t)


def undo_patch_thread_modules():
    for t in threading_modules_to_patch:
        try:
            t.start_new_thread = t._original_start_new_thread
        except:
            pass

        try:
            t.start_new = t._original_start_new_thread
        except:
            pass

        try:
            t._start_new_thread = t._original_start_new_thread
        except:
            pass
```

I updated Python (installed version 3.12.2), updated the libraries I am using, but the issue was not resolved.
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: What's `threading_modules_to_patch`? Please share enough code so that people can try to reproduce your issue

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code you shared, but is your question simply this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319268/what-happened-to-thread-start-new-thread-in-python-3

Comment: @Grismar I do not know what it is, I do not have enough knowledge with the threading, the third code I provided which contains the *threading_modules_to_patch* I took from the debugpy library, I upgraded it but it did not work

Comment: The error happens when `thread_module.start_new_thread` is used as a value. So, apparently `patch_thread_module` was called with a value for `thread_module` that does not have a `start_new_thread` method or attribute. The only place in the code you shared where it gets called is inside the `for t in threading_modules_to_patch` loop and it's `t` that gets passed. So, apparently some (or all) of the contents of `threading_modules_to_patch` don't have a `start_new_thread` - but since you provide no code or import, we can't tell. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If any body faces the same problem:

I solved it by deleting the "thread" library (pip uninstall thread),

the threading in asyncio is conflicting with the "thread" library in Python